# React native, What's com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity

Tags: android, react-native, android-manifest

There is 2 activities inside `AndroidManifest.xml` when you init new project by `react-native`, the first one is `MainActivity` and the second one is  `com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity`. What's the usage of the second one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find explanation of this activity at the header of the file

> DevSettingsActivity.java under
>   $ProjectRoot\node_modules\react-native\ReactAndroid\src\main\java\com\facebook\react\devsupport\DevSettingsActivity.java:
>
> - Activity that display developers settings. Should be added to the debug manifest of the app.
> - Can be triggered through the developers option menu displayed by {@link DevSupportManager}.

Comment: This activity is exposed on the release manifest instead of the debug manifest, which is a bug - read more about it [here](https://github.com/MohGovIL/hamagen-react-native/issues/166)

Answer (score 9):

Adding to the accepted answer, for those who are wondering how to add this activity to debug manifest, follow these steps

1. Add a folder inside `<project_root>/andorid/app/src` and name it `debug`
2. Add a file inside and name it `AndroidManifest.xml`
3. Paste the following code in that file and save.

```
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" tools:targetApi="28" tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning" >
        <!-- This activity will be removed for release builds -->
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity"
              android:exported="false"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

This should be done if you plan on debugging your app over the local network using wireless debugging on Android. 
Hope someone finds this helpful.